# Converging improper integrals: wrong arguments

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I have recently seen a method for proving/disproving the convergence of improper integrals where one partitions the real number line into intervals and considers the sum of the integrals over those intervals. Why is this a valid method, because I could e.g. consider
$$
\begin{align*}
 \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos\left(x \right) dx 
 = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \int_{n\pi}^{n\pi+\pi} \cos\left(x \right) dx
 = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \sin\left(n\pi+\pi \right) -\sin\left(n\pi \right) 
 = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 0 = 0.
\end{align*}
$$
One could probably get any value with this method, it is clearly a wrong argument, isn't it?

Comment: You are correct that without any additional hypothesis (such as integrand being of same sign throughout), it is not correct.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani what if I wanted to dispose that an integral converges. Would the method in this case work, meaning I partition the real line into a sequence of intervals for which the sum of integrals doesn't converge?

Comment: Yes. To elaborate: Let $\{x_n\}_{n \geqslant 1}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive reals such that $x_n \to \infty$. Define $x_0 := 0$. Now, if $\int_0^\infty f$ exists, then in particular, we have that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{x_n} f$$ exists. But the term within the limit above is simply $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \int_{x_{k - 1}}^{x_k} f.$$ (Hopefully it is clear how a partition of $\Bbb R$ into intervals gives a sequence as above and vice-versa.)

Comment: It would be correct to say that if $\int_0^\infty \cos x\,dx$ converges,  then your displayed equations would follow. But that doesn't prove $\int_0^\infty \cos x\,dx$ converges.